Why does plotly::ggplotly() not work in this case?
My plot is created with ggplot something similar to this:
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)

dat <- expand.grid(
    year=2000:2020,
    letter=letters[1:3],
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
) 
dat[,"value"] <- runif(nrow(dat))
dat[, "label"] <- sprintf("%s (%d): %.3f", dat[,"letter"], dat[, "year"], dat[,"value"])

p <- ggplot2::ggplot(dat, ggplot2::aes(x = year, group=letter, y=value, text=label)) +
    ggplot2::geom_line(ggplot2::aes(color=letter), linewidth=1.1) 

When printed, the plot looks as expected. However, if I want to add some interactivity using ggplotly,
plotly::ggplotly(p)

I get an error message
Fehler in train(..., self = self) : 
  unbenutztes Argument (list("year", "value", "letter", "label", "letter"))

What am I doing wrong?
EDIT: After updating ggplot2, it works.

Works fine for me using `plotly'  ‘4.10.4’ and 'ggplot2'   ‘3.5.1’

Have you considered updating Plotly?

After updating it just works. I think I keep the question in case someone else does not know how to act on the error message.
